# How do I capitalise column names more efficiently?

Tags: r, regex, dataframe, capitalization

I want to capitalise certain words ("for", "in", "and", "of") in the column names of a data.frame. My current approach is laborious and inefficient. Any help to improve it.

**Example dataset** (mine is much longer)

```
a <- runif(10, 0,100)
b <- runif(10, 0,100)
c <- runif(10, 0,100)
d <- runif(10, 0,100)

df <- cbind(a,b,c,d)
colnames(df) <- c("NamesofPeople", "HereandThere", "AllforOne", "LetMein")
```

**Current Approach**

```
colnames(df) <- str_replace_all(colnames(filename), "NamesofPeople", "NamesOfPeople")
colnames(df) <- str_replace_all(colnames(filename), "HereandThere", "HereAndThere")
colnames(df) <- str_replace_all(colnames(filename), "AllforOne", "AllForOne")
colnames(df) <- str_replace_all(colnames(filename), "LetMein", "LetMeIn")
```

**Caution**

I would need to be careful if these letters are contained in other columns as part of a word e.g. "of" would also be in "software" and capitalising it would result in "sOftware".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to work with a regular expression:

```
colnames(df) <- str_replace_all(colnames(df), 
              pattern = c("of([A-Z]|$)" = "Of\\1", 
                          "and([A-Z]|$)" = "And\\1", 
                          "for([A-Z]|$)" = "For\\1",
                           "in([A-Z]|$)" = "In\\1")
                  )
```

Here I check if any of the Keywords (of, and, for, in) is at the end of a string (`$`) or followed by a capital letter (`[A-Z]`)